# Hit Counter for List Item

Tags: 2010, publishing, web-analytics

I am working on custom solution that works like a blog. I have a list that contains articles, and I have publishing page that takes the list item id in the URL and query the list to display it.

Now I want to display the hit counter for each article, which is an item in list. Is there an OTB feature in SharePoint Web Analytics, or should I implement it myself by updating the list item with its hit count each time it is retrieved?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same thing. Can you share your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find a solution OTB, so I decided to go with a custom solution.

I am adding new Column "Hit Counter" on the list, and updating it each time the post is loaded.

Answer (score 4):

You can get usage data of the respective SPWeb, and filter out the statistics of a specific list item.

```
DataTable usageDt = SPContext.Current.Web.GetUsageData(SPUsageReportType.url, SPUsagePeriodType.lastMonth);

foreach (DataRow dr in usageDt.Rows)
{
    if(dr["Page"].ToString().ToLower().Equals("myitem.docx"))
    {
        Response.Write("Page: " + dr["Page"].ToString().ToLower() + " Hits: " + dr["Total Hits"].ToString());        
    }
}
```

Note that GetUsageData only returns 2000 records from the usage data for the site. If you run into that limitation, [GetUsageBlob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470705.aspx) needs to be used (don't have experience of that).

Comment: Thanks Jussi, but this didnt work with me as it returned the hits for the pages, but not the list items